# Equivalent to max group by in mdx

Tags: ssas, mdx

How do I get the sales for the last product of a cross join of each product group and brand? I had a look at the Tail function but I can't get it to work properly.

This is the MDX I have so far:

```
SELECT {[Measures].[Sales Amount]} ON COLUMNS,
{
    [Dim Brands].[Brand Name].[Brand Name].ALLMEMBERS *
    [Dim Product Groups].[Product Group Name].[Product Group Name].ALLMEMBERS *
    Tail ([Dim Products].[Product Name].[Product Name].ALLMEMBERS)
}
```

It only returns the last product for the whole cube rather than the last product for each brand and product group.

Comment: you want the last `[Product Name]` for each  `[Product Group Name]`? Or do you just want the last member of `[Product Name]` against every  `[Product Group Name]`?

Comment: last [Product Name] for each [Product Group Name]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `GENERATE` function to generate the product for every combo or Brand and product group. The `EXISTING` takes care of the scope.

```
WITH SET LastProductForEachBrandAndProductGroup AS

    GENERATE

    (
       EXISTING
        NonEmpty
        (
            [Dim Brands].[Brand Name].[Brand Name].ALLMEMBERS, [Dim Product Groups].[Product Group Name].[Product Group Name].ALLMEMBERS
        )

    ,

    Tail (
            [Dim Products].[Product Name].[Product Name].ALLMEMBERS
         )

    )


SELECT {[Measures].[Sales Amount]} ON COLUMNS,
NonEmpty({
    [Dim Brands].[Brand Name].[Brand Name].ALLMEMBERS *
    [Dim Product Groups].[Product Group Name].[Product Group Name].ALLMEMBERS *
    LastProductForEachBrandAndProductGroup
}) ON ROWS
FROM YourCube
```

If by last, you imply the last member in any sorted(by some measure) list, the above would need some more work. Let me know how it works out for you.

Comment: that makes sense I'll give it a go soon and let you know how it goes thanks

Comment: the query takes way too long to complete, I'll have a look at improving it's performance and if it works I'll mark this as the answer thanks

Comment: Edited my answer by adding `NonEmpty`. Please check if it is faster now.

Comment: please also try NON EMPTY on rows

Comment: that was the first thing I tried but it didn't improve it, not sure how long it takes in total but I waited 1 minute and it didn't finish. I think it's something wrong with my data warehouse not the query. I'll try add proper hierarchies between the dimensions and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Well GENERATE is an iterative function - so even though it is a powerful function it can also be slow. Maybe there is another solution. Your request is not an uncommon one.

Comment: I'm quite new to mdx so do you know of any other ways this can be solved?

Comment: Yes, there is. Build appropriate hierarchy in cube...`Product Group -->Brand--->Product`

Comment: will it no longer need the generate function if the hierarchy is there?

Comment: It will, but the query should speed up

Comment: Question - Do you need the last product (& brand) for each product group OR...the last product for every (Product Group, Brand) combination?

Comment: the second option, there are actually more dimensions that I may potentially need as well which don't have any hierarchies defined so I'll definitely do that first anyway because it would speed everything else up. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Separating out the sets should speed this script up. Like the following:

```
WITH 
  SET [allBrands] AS 
    [Dim Brands].[Brand Name].[Brand Name].ALLMEMBERS 
  SET [allGroups] AS 
    [Dim Product Groups].[Product Group Name].[Product Group Name].ALLMEMBERS 
  SET [A] AS 
    Generate
    (
      {[allBrands] * [allGroups]} AS s
     ,
        s.Current
      * 
        Tail
        (
          NonEmpty
          (
            [Dim Products].[Product Name].[Product Name].ALLMEMBERS
           ,[Measures].[Sales Amount]
          )
         ,1
        )
    ) 
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {[Measures].[Sales Amount]} ON 0
 ,NON EMPTY 
    [A] ON 1
FROM [YourCube];
```

Against Microsoft's AdvWrks a similar, and maybe more useful, variant of the above would be to use `TopCount` rather than the slightly artitrary `Tail`:

```
WITH 
  SET [allYears] AS 
    [Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year].MEMBERS 
  SET [allCountries] AS 
    [Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].MEMBERS 
  SET [A] AS 
    Generate
    (
    {[allYears] * [allCountries]} AS s
     ,
        s.Current
      * 
        TopCount
        (
          [Product].[Product Categories].[Product].ALLMEMBERS
         ,2
         ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
        )
    ) 
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]} ON 0
 ,[A] ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

This results in the following:

[image]